# How to prevent Scala's XML PrettyPrinter class from removing newlines

Tags: xml, scala

The `PrettyPrinter` XML formatter removes newlines from character data. How do I prevent this?

```
scala> import scala.xml._
import scala.xml._

scala> """line one
     | line two"""
res0: java.lang.String = 
line one
line two

scala> new PrettyPrinter(999, 3).format(Elem(null, "multiline", Null, TopScope, PCData(res0)))
res1: String = <multiline><![CDATA[line one line two]]></multiline>
```

Also see https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/4303.

Answer (score 1):

You might try using ConstructingParser to escape your string, as detailed here:

http://blog.markfeeney.com/2011/03/scala-xml-gotchas.html